# I need help making a discord py temp mute command in discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I got my discord bot to have a mute command but you have to unmute the user yourself at a later time, I want to have another command called "tempmute" that mutes a member for a certain number of minutes/hours/ or days, this is my code so far, how would I make a temp mute command out of this?

```py
#mute command 
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("Who do you want me to mute?")
        return
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="muted")
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send("ok I did it")
```

Comment: I'm not that great with python, but generally you'd want to do this with dates. You can store a date in a database or (not recommended) variable, then periodically check if that date has passed and then unmute the user once it has.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to how you gave them a role to mute them, just add another parameter to take in how long you want them to be muted in seconds. Then you can use await asyncio.sleep(mute_time) before removing that role.

The code will look something like:

```
import asyncio

#mute command 
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, mute_time : int):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("Who do you want me to mute?")
        return
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="muted")
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send("ok I did it")

    await asyncio.sleep(mute_time)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send("ok times up")
```

Comment: What if I need to do 1h, 1d or 1w?

Answer (score 2):

```
import asyncio

@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member,time):
    muted_role=discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    time_convert = {"s":1, "m":60, "h":3600,"d":86400}
    tempmute= int(time[0]) * time_convert[time[-1]]
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await member.add_roles(muted_role)
    embed = discord.Embed(description= f"✅ **{member.display_name}#{member.discriminator} muted successfuly**", color=discord.Color.green())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5)
    await asyncio.sleep(tempmute)
    await member.remove_roles(muted_role)
```

Comment: Welcome. Try to add some explanation to your answer to improve quality and general understanding.

Comment: May i know what is `time convert` ?

Comment: I think it isn`t very good solution. If bot crashed or turned off, role would stay forever.