# Discord.py mute command

Tags: python, command, mute

So I finished my mute command then I tested it out on one person and it worked. But when it comes to muting to different people it doesn't. I muted one person for 1 minute and the other person for 10 seconds. Since I did the 1m mute first it did that mute first then after that I did the 10 second mute on a different person. It waited till the one minute mute had finished before doing the 10 second mute.How do I stop this from happening?
here is my code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("Mod")
async def mute(ctx, user : discord.Member, duration = 0,*, unit = None):
    roleobject = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, id=730016083871793163)
    await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: Muted {user} for {duration}{unit}")
    await user.add_roles(roleobject)
    if unit == "s":
        wait = 1 * duration
        time.sleep(wait)
    elif unit == "m":
        wait = 60 * duration
        time.sleep(wait)
    await user.remove_roles(roleobject)
    await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: {user} was unmuted")
```

There are no errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `time.sleep(wait)`, this halts all other code until the `wait` time period is over. When you are using `time.sleep` python does not accept any other inputs because it is still 'busy' with sleeping.

You should look into [coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) to solve this problem.

This post give a great example of what you are trying to achieve: [I need help making a discord py temp mute command in discord py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903218/i-need-help-making-a-discord-py-temp-mute-command-in-discord-py)

I *think* this edit should work:

```
#This should be at your other imports at the top of your code
import asyncio

async def mute(ctx, user : discord.Member, duration = 0,*, unit = None):
    roleobject = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, id=730016083871793163)
    await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: Muted {user} for {duration}{unit}")
    await user.add_roles(roleobject)
    if unit == "s":
        wait = 1 * duration
        await asyncio.sleep(wait)
    elif unit == "m":
        wait = 60 * duration
        await asyncio.sleep(wait)
    await user.remove_roles(roleobject)
    await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: {user} was unmuted")
```

Comment: @jwjw2069 Don't forget to mark my answer as correct if this helped you.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about this website. Your code did help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

since discord.py 2.0 was released, you should use `discord.Member.timeout`. I coded a `app_command` wich timeouts a specified member for, in argument given, time.

*Code:*

```
@app_commands.command(name="mute", description="mutes specified member.")
    @app_commands.default_permissions(moderate_members=True)
    async def timeout(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, seconds: int = 0, minutes: int = 0, hours: int = 0, days: int = 0, weeks: int = 0, reason: str = None):
        duration = datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds, minutes=minutes, hours= hours, days=days, weeks=weeks)
        await member.timeout(duration, reason=reason)
        await ctx.response.send_message(f"{member.mention} has been muted until <t:{duration}:R>.")
```